# Caused by: java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: org.apache.cxf.transport.AbstractTransportFactory

Tags: java, spring

When I try to build my spring after integrating webservices in it, I got below error.Can someone help on these?
  The below is error

> org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'XDREndpoint': Invocation of init method failed; nested exception is javax.xml.ws.WebServiceException: org.apache.cxf.service.factory.ServiceConstructionException: Failed to create service.
>                   at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.initializeBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1553)
>                   at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:539)
>                   at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:475)
>                   at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory$1.getObject(AbstractBeanFactory.java:304)
>                   at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:228)
>                   at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:300)
>                   at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:195)
>                   at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.preInstantiateSingletons(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:700)
>                   at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.finishBeanFactoryInitialization(AbstractApplicationContext.java:760)
>                   at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.refresh(AbstractApplicationContext.java:482)
>                   at org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoader.configureAndRefreshWebApplicationContext(ContextLoader.java:403)
>                   at org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoader.initWebApplicationContext(ContextLoader.java:306)
>                   at org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoaderListener.contextInitialized(ContextLoaderListener.java:106)
>                   at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.listenerStart(StandardContext.java:4853)
>                   at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.startInternal(StandardContext.java:5314)
>           Caused by: javax.xml.ws.WebServiceException: org.apache.cxf.bus.extension.ExtensionException: Could not create object of extension class org.apache.cxf.binding.soap.SoapTransportFactory.
>                   at org.apache.cxf.jaxws.EndpointImpl.doPublish(EndpointImpl.java:375)
>                   at org.apache.cxf.jaxws.EndpointImpl.publish(EndpointImpl.java:255)
>                   at org.apache.cxf.jaxws.EndpointImpl.publish(EndpointImpl.java:543)
>                   at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
>                   at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
>                   at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
>                   at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:497)
>                   at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.invokeCustomInitMethod(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1681)
>                   at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.invokeInitMethods(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1620)
>                   at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.initializeBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1549)
>
> Caused by: java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: org.apache.cxf.transport.AbstractTransportFactory.(Ljava/util/List;Lorg/apache/cxf/Bus;)V

Comment: Possible duplicate of [What is a NullPointerException, and how do I fix it?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/218384/what-is-a-nullpointerexception-and-how-do-i-fix-it)

Comment: Most likely jar version mismatch, post your build dependencies and check if correct version of jars are there in build path

Comment: @cramopy how is that even related?

Answer (score 3):

The problem is that you have different versions for your CXF dependencies. Set the same version for all your CXF dependencies will solve your problem. Note that some dependencies have been moved, changed, replaced or removed from a version to another: you may need to adapt your dependencies in order to have everything ok.

Answer (score -2):

```
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/maven-v4_0_0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
    <groupId>com.glenwood.glaceemr</groupId>
    <artifactId>glaceemr</artifactId>
    <packaging>war</packaging>
    <version>5.0-SNAPSHOT</version>
    <name>GlaceEMR Backend</name>
    <url>http://maven.apache.org</url>
    <properties>
        <spring.version>4.0.1.RELEASE</spring.version>
        <jackson.version>2.5.0</jackson.version>
        <version.org.json>20080701</version.org.json>
        <junit.version>4.11</junit.version>
        <postgresqljdbc.version>9.1-901.jdbc4</postgresqljdbc.version>
        <servlet.version>3.0.1</servlet.version>
        <dbcp.version>1.4</dbcp.version>


        <!-- Maven -->
        <maven-surefire-plugin.version>2.9</maven-surefire-plugin.version>
        <maven-failsafe-plugin.version>2.12</maven-failsafe-plugin.version>
        <maven-compiler-plugin.version>2.5.1</maven-compiler-plugin.version>
        <maven-war-plugin.version>2.2</maven-war-plugin.version>
        <maven-deploy-plugin.version>2.7</maven-deploy-plugin.version>
        <tomcat-maven-plugin.version>2.0</tomcat-maven-plugin.version>
        <jetty-plugin.version>8.1.0.v20120127</jetty-plugin.version>

        <target.jdk>1.7</target.jdk>
        <webappDirectory>${project.build.directory}/${project.build.finalName}</webappDirectory>
        <project.build.sourceEncoding>UTF-8</project.build.sourceEncoding>
        <project.reporting.outputEncoding>UTF-8</project.reporting.outputEncoding>
        <project.deployment.encoding>UTF-8</project.deployment.encoding>

    </properties>
    <dependencies>

        <!-- Spring Servlet -->

        <dependency>
            <groupId>javax.servlet</groupId>
            <artifactId>javax.servlet-api</artifactId>
            <version>3.0.1</version>
        </dependency>

        <!-- javax validation -->

        <dependency>
            <groupId>javax.validation</groupId>
            <artifactId>validation-api</artifactId>
            <version>1.0.0.GA</version>
        </dependency>

        <!-- Swagger integration -->
        <!-- <dependency>
            <groupId>com.mangofactory</groupId>
            <artifactId>swagger-springmvc</artifactId>
            <version>0.8.8</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.mangofactory</groupId>
            <artifactId>swagger-springmvc</artifactId>
            <version>0.5.2</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.mangofactory</groupId>
            <artifactId>swagger-springmvc</artifactId>
            <version>0.9.5</version>
        </dependency> -->

        <!-- Spring 4 dependencies -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.ws</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-ws-core</artifactId>
            <version>2.4.0.RELEASE</version>
        </dependency>
    <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.commons</groupId>
            <artifactId>commons-lang3</artifactId>
            <version>3.2.1</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.httpcomponents</groupId>
            <artifactId>httpclient</artifactId>
            <version>4.5.2</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.santuario</groupId>
            <artifactId>xmlsec</artifactId>
            <version>2.0.7</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.wss4j</groupId>
            <artifactId>wss4j-ws-security-dom</artifactId>
            <version>2.1.8</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-core</artifactId>
            <version>${spring.version}</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-context</artifactId>
            <version>${spring.version}</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-webmvc</artifactId>
            <version>${spring.version}</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-web</artifactId>
            <version>${spring.version}</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-jdbc</artifactId>
            <version>${spring.version}</version>
        </dependency>


        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-oxm</artifactId>
            <version>${spring.version}</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-orm</artifactId>
            <version>${spring.version}</version>
        </dependency>


        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-aop</artifactId>
            <version>${spring.version}</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.security</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-security-web</artifactId>
            <version>3.2.3.RELEASE</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.security</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-security-config</artifactId>
            <version>3.2.3.RELEASE</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-test</artifactId>
            <version>3.2.3.RELEASE</version>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>



        <!-- Spring Data REST -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.data</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-data-rest-webmvc</artifactId>
            <version>2.0.0.RC1</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.hateoas</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-hateoas</artifactId>
            <version>0.9.0.RELEASE</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.data</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-data-jpa</artifactId>
            <version>1.5.0.RC1</version>
        </dependency>

        <!-- Hibernate / JPA -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.hibernate.javax.persistence</groupId>
            <artifactId>hibernate-jpa-2.1-api</artifactId>
            <version>1.0.0.Final</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.hibernate</groupId>
            <artifactId>hibernate-entitymanager</artifactId>
            <version>4.3.0.Final</version>
            <scope>runtime</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.hibernate</groupId>
            <artifactId>hibernate-annotations</artifactId>
            <version>3.5.6-Final</version>
        </dependency>

        <!-- Postgresql jdbc -->

        <dependency>
            <groupId>postgresql</groupId>
            <artifactId>postgresql</artifactId>
            <version>${postgresqljdbc.version}</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>commons-dbcp</groupId>
            <artifactId>commons-dbcp</artifactId>
            <version>${dbcp.version}</version>
        </dependency>

        <!-- Jackson JSON Mapper -->

        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.fasterxml.jackson.core</groupId>
            <artifactId>jackson-core</artifactId>
            <version>${jackson.version}</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.fasterxml.jackson.core</groupId>
            <artifactId>jackson-databind</artifactId>
            <version>${jackson.version}</version>
        </dependency>

        <!-- jackson lazy loading serializer -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.fasterxml.jackson.datatype</groupId>
            <artifactId>jackson-datatype-hibernate4</artifactId>
            <version>${jackson.version}</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.json</groupId>
            <artifactId>json</artifactId>
            <version>${version.org.json}</version>
        </dependency>

        <!-- Junit Testing -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>junit</groupId>
            <artifactId>junit</artifactId>
            <version>${junit.version}</version>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.mockito</groupId>
            <artifactId>mockito-core</artifactId>
            <version>1.9.5</version>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.assertj</groupId>
            <artifactId>assertj-core</artifactId>
            <version>1.3.0</version>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.hamcrest</groupId>
            <artifactId>hamcrest-core</artifactId>
            <version>1.3</version>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.github.springtestdbunit</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-test-dbunit</artifactId>
        <version>1.0.0</version>
        <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.dbunit</groupId>
        <artifactId>dbunit</artifactId>
        <version>2.4.8</version>
        <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>

        <!-- Joda time -->

        <dependency>
            <groupId>joda-time</groupId>
            <artifactId>joda-time</artifactId>
            <version>2.3</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.jadira.usertype</groupId>
            <artifactId>usertype.core</artifactId>
            <version>3.2.0.GA</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.jadira.usertype</groupId>
            <artifactId>usertype.jodatime</artifactId>
            <version>2.0.1</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.fasterxml.jackson.datatype</groupId>
            <artifactId>jackson-datatype-joda</artifactId>
            <version>2.4.0-rc2</version>
        </dependency>
        <!-- Query dsl -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.mysema.querydsl</groupId>
            <artifactId>querydsl-core</artifactId>
            <version>3.5.0</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.mysema.querydsl</groupId>
            <artifactId>querydsl-apt</artifactId>
            <version>3.5.0</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.mysema.querydsl</groupId>
            <artifactId>querydsl-jpa</artifactId>
            <version>3.5.0</version>
        </dependency>
        <!-- CXF -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.cxf</groupId>
            <artifactId>cxf-rt-frontend-jaxws</artifactId>
            <version>3.1.10</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>

            <groupId>org.apache.cxf</groupId>
            <artifactId>cxf-rt-ws-security</artifactId>
            <version>3.1.10</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.cxf</groupId>
            <artifactId>cxf-rt-transports-http</artifactId>
            <version>2.4.10</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.cxf</groupId>
            <artifactId>cxf-core</artifactId>
            <version>3.1.10</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.cxf</groupId>
            <artifactId>cxf-rt-ws-policy</artifactId>
            <version>3.1.10</version>
        </dependency>
         <dependency>
        <groupId>org.apache.cxf</groupId>
        <artifactId>cxf-rt-bindings-soap</artifactId>
        <version>2.5.2</version>
    </dependency>

        <!-- Misc -->

        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.jayway.jsonpath</groupId>
            <artifactId>json-path</artifactId>
            <version>0.9.1</version>
        </dependency>
<dependency>
            <groupId>org.projectlombok</groupId>
            <artifactId>lombok</artifactId>
            <version>0.12.0</version>
            <scope>provided</scope>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>
    <build>
        <!-- Generate compiled stuff in the folder used for developing mode -->
        <finalName>glaceemr</finalName>
        <outputDirectory>${webappDirectory}/WEB-INF/classes</outputDirectory>

        <resources>
            <resource>
                <directory>src/main/resources</directory>
            </resource>
        </resources>

        <testResources>
            <testResource>
                <directory>src/test/resources</directory>
            </testResource>
        </testResources>

        <plugins>

            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>${maven-compiler-plugin.version}</version>
                <configuration>
                    <source>${target.jdk}</source>
                    <target>${target.jdk}</target>
                    <encoding>${project.build.sourceEncoding}</encoding>
                    <proc>none</proc>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>

            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-surefire-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>2.9</version>
                <configuration>
                    <includes>
                        <include>**/*Test.java</include>
                    </includes>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>


    <!-- querydsl -->

            <plugin>
                <groupId>com.mysema.maven</groupId>
                <artifactId>apt-maven-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>1.1.1</version>
                <executions>
                    <execution>
                        <phase>generate-sources</phase>
                        <goals>
                            <goal>process</goal>
                        </goals>
                        <configuration>
                            <!-- Specifies the directory in which the query types are generated -->
                            <outputDirectory>target/generated-sources</outputDirectory>
                            <!-- States that the APT code generator should look for JPA annotations -->
                            <processor>com.mysema.query.apt.jpa.JPAAnnotationProcessor</processor>
                        </configuration>
                    </execution>
                </executions>
            </plugin>
<plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>2.5.1</version>
                <configuration>
                    <source>1.7</source>
                    <target>1.7</target>
                    <compilerArguments>
                        <processor>lombok.core.AnnotationProcessor,org.hibernate.jpamodelgen.JPAMetaModelEntityProcessor</processor>
                    </compilerArguments>
                </configuration>
                <dependencies>
                    <dependency>
                        <groupId>org.hibernate</groupId>
                        <artifactId>hibernate-jpamodelgen</artifactId>
                        <version>1.3.0.Final</version>
                        <scope>compile</scope>
                    </dependency>
                </dependencies>
            </plugin>


        </plugins>
    </build>

    <pluginRepositories>
        <pluginRepository>
            <id>apache.snapshots</id>
            <name>Apache Snapshots</name>
            <url>https://repository.apache.org/content/repositories/snapshots/</url>
            <releases>
                <enabled>false</enabled>
            </releases>
            <snapshots>
                <enabled>true</enabled>
            </snapshots>
        </pluginRepository>
    </pluginRepositories>
    <repositories>
        <repository>
            <id>spring-milestone</id>
            <name>Spring Maven MILESTONE Repository</name>
            <url>http://repo.springsource.org/libs-milestone</url>
        </repository>


        <!-- Swaggger Based Repository -->
        <repository>
            <id>jcenter-release</id>
            <name>jcenter</name>
            <url>http://oss.jfrog.org/artifactory/oss-release-local/</url>
        </repository>

    </repositories>
</project>
```

Comment: Could you explain your answer